# Calculate Height from NSAttributedString with NSParagraphStyle

Tags: ios, objective-c, height, core-text, nsattributedstring

I want to calculate the height of a `NSAttributedString` with the `NSParagraphStyle` attribute.

I thought it will be easy to create a UILabel with higher spacing between the lines but i can't calculate the right height for my `UITableViewCell`.

I tried to calculate it with `boundingRectWithSize:options:` but it's not working at all…

Comment: Isn't the *size* property returning the correct value?

Comment: Nope the size is returning a redicilous width.

Comment: Have you set the font in the attributes dictionary?

Comment: that's the trick! omg why is this not even documented?

Comment: It's something pretty straightforward if you think that a font defines how characters are drawn.

Comment: That's already pretty good, but doesn't give exact results. The CGRects height is still a bit too small actually.

Answer (score 1):

I use [NSLayoutManager's `usedRectForTextContainer:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSLayoutManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLayoutManager/usedRectForTextContainer%3a) with a TextView stack disconnected from a UITableView. I answered a [similar Stack Overflow question and explained how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23411223/2806963) to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

When the convinient methods from apple dont work, this category provides a good aproximation in most cases.

```
@implementation NSAttributedString (PixLib)

- (CGFloat)heightForWidth:(CGFloat)width {
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 99999));
    CGFloat h = [self heightForPath:path];
    CGPathRelease(path);
    return h;
}

- (CGFloat)heightForPath:(CGPathRef)path {
    CGFloat height = 0;
    CTFrameRef frame =  [self cfframeForPath:path];
    if (frame != NULL) {
        NSArray* lines = (__bridge NSArray*)CTFrameGetLines(frame);

        int l = [lines count];
        if (l > 1) {
            CGPoint origins[l];

            CTFrameGetLineOrigins(frame, CFRangeMake(0, l), origins);

            CGFloat yFirst = origins[0].y;
            CGFloat yLast = origins[l-1].y;

            CGFloat ascent, descent, leading;
            CTLineGetTypographicBounds((__bridge CTLineRef)[lines objectAtIndex:l-1], &ascent, &descent, &leading);

            height = ceilf((ascent+descent+leading)*1.3) + yFirst-yLast;
        } else {
            if (l==1) {
                CGFloat ascent, descent, leading;
                CTLineGetTypographicBounds((__bridge CTLineRef)[lines objectAtIndex:0], &ascent, &descent, &leading);
                height = ceilf(ascent+descent+leading)*1.3;
            }
        }
        CFRelease(frame);
    }
    return height;
}

- (CTFrameRef)cfframeForPath:(CGPathRef)p {
    // hack to avoid bugs width different behavior in iOS <4.3 and >4.3
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGRect r = CGPathGetBoundingBox(p);

    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t, r.origin.x, r.origin.y);
    t = CGAffineTransformScale(t, 1, -1);
    t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t, r.origin.x, - ( r.origin.y + r.size.height ));
    CGPathAddPath(path, &t, p);

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    // hack end

    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)self);
    CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, NULL);

    CFRelease(framesetter);
    CGPathRelease(path);
    return frame;
}

@end
```

Comment: it doesn't work with the line spacing. I add a NSParagrahStyle to the NSAttributedLabel but it doesn't calculate the linespacing…