# Can't seem to calculate correct line-height of NSAttributedString for a UILabel

Tags: ios, ios7, nsattributedstring

I'm using `NSAttributedString's` `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:` method to calculate the expected height for some text, after reading [this article from objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-9/string-rendering.html)

```
+(CGSize)postLabelSizeForPost:(ANKPost *)post
{
  CGFloat labelWidth = 220.0f;
  NSAttributedString *text = [BXTPostCell mutableAttributedStringForPost:post];
  NSStringDrawingOptions options = NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading;
  CGRect boundingRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(labelWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                         options:options
                                         context:nil];
  CGFloat height = (CGFloat) (ceil(boundingRect.size.height));

  return CGSizeMake(labelWidth, height);
}
```

However, when I use this method, the text doesn't actually fit inside this size - the size is consistently too short.

At first, I'd thought the issue was with emoji characters - but it seems to be happening for many tableviewcells in the app.

**Update:**
I've talked with a few folks, and it sounds like the issue may be an underlying bug with `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:`. I figured out a workaround: create a dummy `UILabel`, give it the same attributes as the `UILabel` in the tableview cell (`numberOfLines`, etc) and then use `sizeThatFits:` to calculate the size. It's a hack, to be sure - but it solves my problem sufficiently. I wish it were more elegant, though!

Answer (score 4):

I came across this same effect when trying to calculate the size of attributed text for a UITextView. I ran across [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18859917/2806963).

The trick is to use [NSLayoutManager's `usedRectForTextContainer:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSLayoutManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLayoutManager/usedRectForTextContainer:). What is neat is that this method doesn't need to be used in conjunction with a UITextView. This means that you can use it off of the mainThread, key for pre-calculation of UITableViewCell heights.

Here's how I use it:

```
- (CGSize)rectForAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)string withSize:(CGSize)theSize
{
    if (!string || CGSizeEqualToSize(theSize, CGSizeZero)) {
        return CGSizeZero;
    }

    // setup TextKit stack
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:theSize];
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:string];
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

    // query for size
    CGRect rect = [layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer];

    return CGSizeMake(ceilf(rect.size.width), ceilf(rect.size.height));
}
```

To make things easier, I created a convenience method to figure out the height for a specific width:

```
- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)string withWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    return [self rectForAttributedString:string withSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX)].height;
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

*PS. I'm kind of new at this whole programming thing so if my code can be optimized please let me know.*

Answer (score 1):

I think, you might not set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`.

This property set constraint to the max width of a view.